# Baker Gill Solvay Relativization Result

Tags: complexity-theory

I am reading the book by Arora and Barak, in which they try to prove there exists a langauge $U$ such that $P^{B} \neq U$.
I completely understood the proof except one problem in the end, they use crucially the fact that a Polynomial Turing Machine will halt within steps $\frac{2^{n}}{10}$ My doubt is it is not necessary, it may happen the constants in the polynomial are so high that for that particular $n$ it takes more than $2^n$ time. So how do you deal with that.It is not specified to take n large enough such that $2^n$ is greater than its running time.

Comment: Those of us without access to Arora–Barak cannot answer the question. But presumably the answer is just what you wrote – for large enough $n$, a polytime Turing machine will halt within $2^n/10$ steps.

Comment: The draft of the book is freely availiable.

Comment: Please include all relevant information and context in the question.  Don't make us go leaf through the book.  Take another look at the book and see whether what they say sounds consistent with what Yuval wrote; then edit the question to include extra information about what they say that seems relevant to that.  I expect this will help you get better answers.